# как прицепить javascript событие для кнопки в wordpress elementorPro

Tags: javascript, elementor

мануалы от яндекса бедны в этом смысле, а документация elementor pro крайне технически красива и мне не понятна, как привязать javascript событие для кнопки из конструктора elementor pro

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так же как и для кнопки из не elementor pro, но лучше бы Вам немножко объяснить.